# ComException: File Not Found

Tags: autocad

I'm trying to open an autocad file on a shared folder but it fails with comexception saying file was not found, but file exists.
Here's the code:("filePath" is the path to the file and acApp is a reference to Autocad object.)

```
if(File.Exists("filePath"))
{
    acApp.Documents.Open("filePath");
}
```

Comment: Any more information? e.g. programming language?

Comment: nobody can access to that shared folder but i have defined a user and set access rights to him.every times that i want to access to my shared folder i loging on that user with an api method.but this time i received this error when i wanted to open a file in that shared folder:
"File <myfilepath> is not found".

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace the path with your shared drive with the UNC version.

Comment: ,my filepath is \\servername\sharedfolder\protectedfolder\file1.dwg. is this path a UNC version path or not?

Comment: If it start with //, it's an UNC path : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Uniform_Naming_Convention

Answer (score 0):

Use `\\` instead of `\`

Use `filePath = "\\servername\\sharedfolder\\protectedfolder\\file1.dwg"`

or

use full path `"D:\\servername\\sharedfolder\\protectedfolder\\file1.dwg"`